# Localhost not recording changes to code?

Tags: javascript, meteor, localhost, refresh

I'm making changes locally to my code. When I save the code in Atom, then refresh over localhost, the changes are not being displayed in the browser. What are the possible reasons for this?

Comment: May b your browser cache is not clear.Kindly try it in "cognito" window in Chrome

Comment: Have you confirmed that meteor itself is seeing the code changes? Do you see in your cmd prompt that it is restarting or refreshing the server?

Comment: Refreshing your browser window after saving a file really shouldn't be neccessary with Meteor. When the app is running, it should automagically refresh itself when a file is changed. Check your CMD (Windows) or terminal (Mac/n*x) screen to see if the app refreshes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really a solution, but mistakes that I sometimes do:

1. Cross check **carefully** if its the same file that your are editing, and the one that's run in the terminal, and browser.

2. Also **carefully** check, when you save the file, is the terminal refreshing the client, or restarting the server.

I have highlighted carefully, because it's happened to me, and I have seen it happen with my colleagues.

Answer (score 1):

try ctrl+f5 to refresh browser. 
or open dev tool in browser then check "disable cache" on settings (chrome)

Answer (score 1):

If clearing cache resolves issue, then from next time you can use browser in **incognito**, or use this chrome ext https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cache-killer/jpfbieopdmepaolggioebjmedmclkbap

Answer (score 0):

Clear cache in the browser, check to make sure Atom is saving the file in the right place and not else where on the computer other things to try is edit the file in notepad or notepad++ and save it and see if it changes. As it could be atom its self not working correctly..